# Does Blender have a file locking feature?

Tags: edit-mode

Is there some way to lock files with a password or to lock open files to prevent them from being edited by others?

## Use case examples:

### A:

Jack wants to sell Blender models, but wants to ensure that only those who have paid and been sent a password can edit the models.
Can a password be used?

### B:

Jack and Jill are making a hill for their water simulation. However, Jack wants to make sure the hill is completed before Jill tries to run a water simulation.
(How) can he lock the file?

#### To be clear:

- LibreOffice (also open source) allows password protected files.
- I do not want to sell files as described, but I do want to protect my files via password sometimes (and will need to in some situations).

Comment: About LibreOffice: it can encrypt a file, if the file's document format supports it. Both ZIP (used by Open Document Format) and PDF supports encryption in their specification.

Answer (score 7):

*No*, for the same reasons ideasman42 said in his own answer. He suggests some workarounds however, here are mine..

**Case A:**
You can use [PasteAll.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend) *(which has natural support for blend files)* to safely upload ***and*** password protect a `.blend` file, you can then send the link and password to the customer.

**Case B:**
Easy enough, they could work in separate *personal* files and merge them when ready. *Link/Append*

Ultimately, you are better off using an actual software that provides encryption such as [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: it is easiest to simply use 7Zip to zip and add password to open the zip. The Ideasman42 answer can have different result later when the implementation of Blender changed. +1 to this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible in Blender.

And it would be quite hard enforce even if the feature was supported in Blender - since its open source, someone could always compile their own version that allowed re-saving.

For case A: just use a video turnaround.

For case B: sounds like they just need good communication/team work. Note that some version-control allows locking so perhaps it can be done at that level.

Comment: I think in case A he was asking more about DRM, which is unlikely to be found in Blender ever.

Comment: Not DRM. LibreOffice allows passwords, for example. It's opensource, but still secure that way. I don't want to do what I mentioned in case A, but I would like to password protect my files sometimes.

Comment: The .blend file format, and Gzip library used to compress it, doesn't include encryption feature. I don't think there's a way to do that from within Blender.

Answer (score 1):

File locking is generally an operating system feature. Blender could try, but it won't work in all platforms.

About encryption with a password, the compression and file format used by Blender is open, and they don't include encryption. You'll need a separate program to protect the file in such way. I think it can be done with an addon using some Python cryptography module, provided it can decrypt to an in-memory image and let Blender read from that, which I haven't seen an API call for (decrypting to temporary file to be loaded defeats the purpose).

Comment: As I understand it "file locking" here doesn't refer to an editing lock (with a lock object or a `.$$lock_somefile.blend.tmp$$` file) but rather to encryption.

Comment: @WChargin The 2nd part of opening sentence made me think he want file locking, and the 2nd use case example are easiest done with such feature. I understood he wants a password, too, hence my 2nd paragraph.