# Is there a "read-only" mode?

Tags: customization, settings

When I'm working with Blender, I usually have some references lying around, either images (using tools like PureRef) or other models. When I look at other models, I open another instance of Blender just to view said models.

That's usually not a big deal, if ever, but I was wondering: is there a way to open a Blender project in "read-only" mode? Where you don't have all your usual fancy tools loaded, but you can just navigate around the scene to look at your model? Basically like regular Blender, except you can't edit anything.

Comment: what about deactivating the Show Overlays option and making the scene full screen?

Comment: @moonboots Maybe I'm missing something, but that still allows you to edit your scene.

Comment: Ctrl Alt Spacebar maybe? You can still edit though but the interface is super limited

Comment: No, there is not, i think it has to do with the fact it's an open source Software, so you can't limit the user experience because another user will be able to move it back to an editable object. But just guessing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/672/does-blender-have-a-file-locking-feature